# Unity C# Improving generic get component method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, interface

I have this:

```
[SerializeField]
protected SearchForInterfaces _searchForInterfaces = SearchForInterfaces.IN_PARENT;

protected T GetComponentAsSpecified<T>()
{
     switch (_searchForInterfaces)
     {
           case SearchForInterfaces.IN_PARENT:
           default:
               return this.GetComponentInParent<T>();
           case SearchForInterfaces.IN_CHILDREN:
               return this.GetComponentInChildren<T>();
           case SearchForInterfaces.IN_COMPONENT:
               return this.GetComponent<T>();
      }
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
_clicker = this.GetComponentAsSpecified<IMouseClicker>();
```

I have this working generic switch to allow me to specify where the monobehaviour should search for it's component parts. I don't like that the switch needs to be repeatedly called. I'd like to cache the result of the switch once, on mono Awake(), then use it to search for all components of that mono.

I tried this:

```
        protected Func<Component> SearchForInterfacesCallback;

        protected virtual void Awake()
        {
            SearchForInterfacesCallback = GetComponentAsSpecifiedCallBack()<Component>;
        }

        protected Func<T> GetComponentAsSpecifiedCallBack<T>()
        {
            switch (_searchForInterfaces)
            {
                case SearchForInterfaces.IN_PARENT:
                default:
                    return this.GetComponentInParent<T>;
                case SearchForInterfaces.IN_CHILDREN:
                    return this.GetComponentInChildren<T>;
                case SearchForInterfaces.IN_COMPONENT:
                    return this.GetComponent<T>;
            }
        }
```

With this usage:

```
_clicker = this.GetComponentAsSpecifiedCallBack<IMouseClicker>();
```

But no dice! Thank you for any assistance. It is much appreciated. Sorry if my post is foolish and thanks for assisting my learning!

Comment: Works for me. Or do you mean to exclude the game object `this` is attached to when searching in parents and children? You'll need to define your own functions instead of using `GetComponentInChildren` or `GetComponentInParent` because [these functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) include the gameobject they are called on [in their searches](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInParent.html).

Comment: Also, please be more descriptive than "no dice" in the future. That could mean anything from it fails to compile, it returns null, it crashes your computer, or as I'm guessing it always returns the `T` attached to the same object as `this` if one is attached ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am aware of the functionality you mentioned, though this is not the issue. The problem is that, and it may be impossible, I want to store a generic func, which could be any of the get component methods, as I define using an enum in the unity editor. The issue is that to store this func it seems I would need to define values ahead of time, which would not allow me to get a component of T type as the first switch allows.

Comment: Using the second switch and call back set up by calling with:
```
_clicker = GetComponentAsSpecifiedCallBack<IMouseClicker>();
```
I get an error of:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<Hll.Input.Interfaces.IMouseClicker>' to 'Hll.Input.Interfaces.IMouseClicker' [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0029)

Comment: Oh snap I added an extra paranthesis pair just now and it worked!